# SOAPUI & SSL_VERIFY_PEER

Tags: ssl, soapui

Using SOAPUI 5 to test a REST web service from a commercial closed source app.  When I run the request via SOAPUI I get the following error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

The docs for this app however do note:

"Some libraries for making HTTP/HTTPS requests (such as cURL) will attempt to verify the certificate of any HTTPS hosts by default. LightSpeed Server uses a custom SSL certificate that will fail this check, so this verification should be disabled to ensure requests are successful. In the HTTP_Request2 package specifically, we disable this check via the following line of code,"

Their recommended solution in PHP is the following:

`$this->req->setConfig("ssl_verify_peer", false);`

Anyone have any idea of how to do this in SoapUI?

Answer (score 0):

The error is returned in a SOAPUI SOAP or REST call when there is no associated SSL with your web service call. You will need a valid Keystore to authenticate the REST web service.

Resolution is to add the keystore to SOAP/REST project and request by following below steps.

1. Double click on the project in SOAPUI.
2. Click on WS-Security Configurations tab
3. Click on Keystores and add the .jks or .pfx file to the project.
4. Then click on the rest request --> Rest Properties --> look for SSL keystore and add the keystore to the request.

You can also add keystore under Preferences and it applies to all projects in workspace.